# Need help with understanding meaning of the sentence

Tags: meaning

Kindly explain the phrase **disease-and germ-ridden**. I also can't understand what word **mild** refers to.

> I understand the health concerns in a world with a **disease-and germ-ridden** public that can't handle any kind of pathogen, however **mild**.

I found the following meanings though:
- gentle in nature or behavior
- not strong in action or effect
- not strong or harsh in taste

Comment: The following is the rule of this community. I believe you have been asked to include your research before.  **If your question isn't adequately answered by these resources, feel free to ask here on English Language and Usage Stack Exchange. Be sure to mention the research you've done and what you're still hoping to learn!** Why are you not following this? Read this [link](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: English like most languages have idiomatic usages for words. I mean certainly most languages have this phrase "the weather today is mild". There is no explanation needed because common sense will tell you what "mild" means in whatever language it is used ! ! !

Comment: Thanx, Rathony! I will do that for sure ;)

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is about the worry for one's health (*health concerns*) when most people (the *public*) are characterized by two things:

1. They are "**disease-and germ-ridden**."  They are sick and infested with germs that make them sick.
2. They "can't handle any kind of **pathogen, however mild**."  Their immune systems cannot fight off even the weakest disease-causing agent.

So you have to worry about getting sick because you come into contact with multitudes of sick people who can't get better.